# Added JWT with nuget, but why does error list still says jwt does not exist in the current context?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, jwt, zendesk

Edit:
So if I remove the reference and right click add reference and add it back in. It shows up in the Object Browser and it is able to resolve the namespace. If I build the project or build the solution though it disappears from the object browser and the error appears again.

I'm trying to integrate ZenDesk into our current software to help tech support track their tickets. To do this I need to set up SSO using some straightforward C# code from github to generate a JSON Web Token.

The project is in Visual Studio 2010 and the code needs JWT to run which I installed from NuGet.

For whatever reason though the namespace won't resolve in the code.

I get two errors right here:

```
 string token = JWT.JsonWebToken.Encode(payload, SHARED_KEY, JWT.JwtHashAlgorithm.HS256);
```

It just says, The name 'JWT' does not exist in the current context. This is a one project solution so everything is in one place. I also cannot view JWT.dll in the Object Browser. Even if I try to put a using directive:

```
using JWT;
```

It still won't resolve.

The version is JWT version 1.3.2.

Any idea why this won't resolve?

Here is the full code:

```
// Handler: <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Zendesk.JWTLogin" CodeBehind="Zendesk.JWTLogin.cs" %>
// Requires: JWT (https://nuget.org/packages/JWT)
// Tested with .NET 4.5

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Zendesk
{
    public class JWTLogin : IHttpHandler
    {
        private const string SHARED_KEY = "{some key}";
        private const string SUBDOMAIN = "{some name}";

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            TimeSpan t = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
            int timestamp = (int)t.TotalSeconds;

            var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
                { "iat", timestamp },
                { "jti", System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString() },
                //{ "external_id", something that gets user PKey },
                // { "name", currentUser.name },
                // { "email", currentUser.email }
            };

            string token = JWT.JsonWebToken.Encode(payload, SHARED_KEY, JWT.JwtHashAlgorithm.HS256);
            string redirectUrl = "https://" + SUBDOMAIN + ".zendesk.com/access/jwt?jwt=" + token;

            context.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After you've run the NuGet command, is the DLL referenced in your project?

Comment: Yes, JWT shows up in my references. When I try to view it in object browser though it won't navigate to it.

Comment: What do you mean "won't navigate to it" - do you get an error message? Is the reference correct - does the DLL exist on disk?

Comment: The dll exists. The file path is correct. I mean it does not display in object browser. If you right click the reference in the solution explorer and click view in object browser it does not show jwt in object browser it just goes to my project.

Comment: Are you working in a .NET 3.5 project? If you're working in .NET 3, JWT is not compatible.

Comment: The Target Framework is .NET 4, but I thought it should be compatible with a later version just not an earlier one.